# Disable F1 key in Windows 7 virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, desktop

I have Windows Virtual PC running Windows XP in windowed (not full-screen) mode.
One of the custom applications that I run in the Virtual PC makes heavy use of F1 key, however every time I press it, in addition to that program's functionality "Windows Virtual PC" help comes up as well!
Is there any way to disable the help or make it so that F1 pressed inside virtual PC does not call it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Virtual machine settings,choose Keyboard: Send Windows key combinations such as Alt-Tab to: Virtual Machine.

The original setting is "In full screen view only". You will need to shut down (not restart) the virtual PC and close the VPC program before starting it up again.